# Determine initial page bundle size programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, react-suspense

My team wrote a web application with `create-react-app` and we want to keep the bundle size small for the initial page load. Right now we're just running `gzip` and `wc` on the outputted javascript files in `build/` to get a sense of the size of the bundle overall (similar to the output of `react-scripts build`), but that isn't granular enough to tell us the size of all the bundles that are required for an initial page load.

For now I'm planning to rely on parsing `build/index.html` and finding which script tags refer to absolute paths (to avoid counting third party scripts) in order to identify which chunks are loaded on the initial page load, though I do wonder if it's possible for code to be loaded javascript-side that would be important for the initial paint. I don't think so but I also don't understand how CRA works enough to say that definitively.

My teammate also is thinking maybe we should just load the landing page in a headless browser and determine what scripts loaded on page load that way, though it'd be nice to have a lighter-weight way to do this check than that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wrote up this bash script that does the parsing of `build/index.html` quick and dirty: `grep -o '<script[^>]*src="/static/js/[^"]*"' build/index.html | sed -n -e 's/^.*src="\([^"]*\).*$/\1/p' | awk '{print "./build" $0}'`. That outputs the js files that start with `/static/js`, referenced directly by `build/index.html`. I'll use this for now unless someone else argues this is a bad approach otherwise.

Comment: You can just open chrome devtools and check in network tab, how much each javascript file size is and how long did it take to initial paint.

Comment: To clarify my use case is for an automated check in CI/tests that ensures that initial bundle hasn’t increased significantly between PRs. So opening up the devtools by hand isn’t really what I’m looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Simply parsing html output won't work if your entry point contains lazy-loaded chunk (either using `React.lazy` or similar method).

With this [PR](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/3945) you can analyze using the JSON output from webpack, by passing `--stats` to `build` script: `yarn build --stats` (if you use `npm` don't forget to use `--` to forward flag to inner scripts: `npm run build -- --stats`)

This will create `build/bundle-stats.json` that you can directly import in nodejs script. It contains list of chunks outputted from webpack and its dependency graph

The only alternative I can think of is using puppeteer, but this is more suited for measuring user-specific metrics, like time to interactive. I'd suggest using simple node scripts for any build time measurement

Comment: I’ll give this a go later and see if I can find a way to tell which chunks are for individual pages (defined by react router).